# Grpc Client-side C++ Channel Destructor taking 10 seconds

Tags: c++, grpc

The purpose of the code was initially to test the operation of the grpc stub when the grpc service was not available. However, the behavior I'm seeing indicates that there's something going on that I don't understand- hence the question.

In this code:

```
#define IN_MILLISECONDS(x) (std::chrono::system_clock::now() + std::chrono::milliseconds(x))

string NowString()
{
    char buf[128];
    SYSTEMTIME timeBuf;
    ::GetLocalTime(&timeBuf);
    sprintf(buf, "%02d:%02d:%02d.%03d - ", timeBuf.wHour, timeBuf.wMinute, timeBuf.wSecond, timeBuf.wMilliseconds);
    return string(buf);
}

void testStub(std::shared_ptr<grpc::Channel> chan)
{
    MessageProcessor::Stub client(chan);

    Void _void;
    AccumulateAmount amount;
    amount.set_amount(42);

    grpc::ClientContext ctx;
    ctx.set_deadline(IN_MILLISECONDS(100));

    cout << NowString() << "    Making RPC\n";
    grpc::Status st = client.Accumulate(&ctx, amount, &_void);
    cout << NowString() << "    Leaving testStub()\n";
}

void test()
{
    auto chan = grpc::CreateChannel("localhost:54321", grpc::InsecureChannelCredentials());

    cout << NowString() << "  Channel Up- Testing Stub\n";
    testStub(chan);
    cout << NowString() << "  Leaving test()\n";
}

int main()
{
    cout << NowString() << "Calling test()\n";
    test();
    cout << NowString() << "Exiting 'main'\n";
    return 1;
}
```

the output is

```
11:42:05.400 - Calling test()
11:42:05.403 -   Channel Up- Testing Stub
11:42:05.404 -     Making RPC
11:42:05.506 -     Leaving testStub()
11:42:05.507 -   Leaving test()
11:42:15.545 - Exiting 'main'
Press any key to continue . . .
```

It should be evident by the timestamps that the destructor for the Channel is taking just over 10 seconds.

My question is this: *What can I do to significantly reduce the time it takes to destroy the grpc Channel?*

Answer (score 0):

Could you check the status of the call? In your code, check `st.ok()` right after `grpc::Status st = client.Accumulate(&ctx, amount, &_void)` (see [this](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/examples/cpp/helloworld/greeter_client.cc#L76) for an example). If `st.ok()` is false, try printing the `st.error_message()` and `st.error_code()` for more info.

It may also be useful to launch it with the environment variable `GRPC_VERBOSITY` set to `debug` (see [this document](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/environment_variables.md) for more info).